# Gunicorn isnt finding 'memcache' module but it is found when I run python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

Tags: python, django, memcached, gunicorn

I'm having trouble with my server. This is a multitenant project, the one in the Windows server is working fine, but the one in Ubuntu is giving me a "No module named 'memcache'" error although it is installed. I know it is installed because I ran a "python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001' and when I accessed by my personal browser worked fine. Gunicorn is pointing properly to my virtual env and there are no  log errors when I restart the service, I'm quite desperate now.

My configuration:

```
CACHE_HOST = os.getenv('cache_host', '127.0.0.1')

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': f'{CACHE_HOST}:11211',
    },
    'estadisticos': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': f'{CACHE_HOST}:11211',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So is your memcache host running on localhost? if not perhaps gunicorn is started as a service and doesn't have the right value of the env var `cache_host`

in any case I'd suggest you add prints at the end of your settings file
and one print to see whether you're using the same ptyhon for gunicorn and your command line:

```
import sys  # if not already imported in settings
print("my python is ", sys.executable)
print("CACHES", CACHES, file=sys.stderr)
```

or if you can't see stdout:
with open("/tmp/mylog.log") as fout:
   print("my python is ", sys.executable, file=fout)
   print("CACHES", CACHES, file=fout)

```
Check that python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001 creates the same trace as running gunicorn.
delete the file `/tmp/mylog.log` between the two runs.
```

If outputs are identical, but memcached is working for one and not the other, then you had to check that the django settings are not overridden somewhere else

Comment: Identical outputs and not overwritten settings :/, my second tenant which is running on windows server has no problem, I'm starting to ask if it's a gunicorn problem since is not recognizing python-memcached, I'm getting the same output as if I do a pip uninstall python-memcached

Comment: changed answer. please check also the output of `sys.executable` perhaps you different virtualenvs / python environments or something like that

Comment: You have just saved me a night because I have a meeting tomorrow morning with the client ! Thank you very much